# Autocomplete search not giving any results - Spring, jquery

Tags: jquery, spring

I am working on autocomplete search with Spring and jquery. 
Problem is when I start typing and when I put first letter of username it doesn't show any results.
In my console I have this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/search?term=t
```

**controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List <User> findUserByUsername(HttpServletRequest request){

        return userRepository.findUserByUsername(request.getParameter("term"));
    }
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT u.username FROM User u WHERE u.username LIKE CONCAT('%',:username,'%')")
    public List<User> findUserByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search"/>
```

**search.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').autocomplete({
        source: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/search'

     });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `source: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/search'` on `source: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}' + '/search'`

Comment: I tried but is not working. First I thought is something in my repo query that is not working but I am not sure any more.